# How do I get .png images with my foreach loop right?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

first of all, I'm sorry for my english, it isn't the best.

Now I have this foreach loops:

```
@foreach(array_combine($land_keys, $land_values) as $key => $value)
   @foreach($all_lands_flag as $flag)
        @if(strtolower($key) == $flag)
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/flags/{{$flag}}.png"/></td>
                <td width="86%">{{$key}}</td>
                <td>{{$value}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

The @ before the php commands like @if, @foreach are because I'm using the laravel framework.

Like you can see I have some arrays in my foreach and they all work's perfect, there aren't any problems. It's more this part:

```
@foreach($all_lands_flag as $flag)
    @if(strtolower($key) == $flag)
        <tr>
            <td><img src="/flags/{{$flag}}.png"/></td>
            <td width="86%">{{$key}}</td>
            <td>{{$value}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

in $flag are just names like 'de', 'usa', 'it' ... 
in $key its the same, I just compare them and if PHP finds flags that are in $key and also in $flag, it should give me them:

```
<img src="/flags/{{$flag}}.png"/>
```

well, but it don't works. If I remove the  {{$flag}}.png and replace it with usa.png, it gives me the usa flag for all array elements. The thing is, I need it like I did in my code, for every land, it own flag.

I hope someone of you can help me! thanks

OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS:

```
 Flag:         Land: Quantity:
'germany flag' DE    155
'italian flag' IT    100
'usa flag'     USA   55
```

Outputs:

```
$all_lands_flag = array('cn', 'fr', 'us', 'at', 'il', 'ua', 'de', 'us', 'eu', 'ru', 'br', 'gb', 'nl', 'lu', 'it', 'other');
```

$land_keys output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "US"
    [1] => "DE"
    [2] => "BR"
    [3] => "FR"
    [4] => "other"
)
```

$land_values

```
Array
(
    [0] => 186
    [1] => 44
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 7
)
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? after loop with `<img src="/flags/{{$flag}}.png"/>` runs you don't see images ?

Comment: In your controller method, can you `var_dump` & `exit` this `array_combine($land_keys, $land_values)` and `$all_lands_flag` - what is your output?

Comment: By which name the flag has been saved? By two letters of the country/laguage or by number?

Comment: by two of the letters

Comment: For me seems code is ok, seems there is some other mistake can you add text markers `---` before @if(strtolower($key) == $flag) and `+++` inside if, and check if you get `+++` in your page

Comment: in your code, inside the if statement, try: {{ print_r($flag); die(); }} and run the code.  See if it outputs anything at all.  Start trying to figure out what is in the variable $flag.  For some reason, it looks like $flag does not contain the expected string.